# Plotting subgraphs identified by connected components

Tags: python, matplotlib, networkx

I have detected connected components in my graph.
Now I would need to plot them in separate charts for analyzing them individually.As example I am using karate club network, but my network has actually 5 connected components.

```
G = nx.karate_club_graph() 

connected_com=[len(c) for c in sorted(nx.connected_components(G), key=len, reverse=True)]
S = [G.subgraph(c).copy() for c in nx.connected_components(G)]
```

I used nx.draw but nothing has been displayed:

```
plt.figure()
nx.draw(S)
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`S` is not a subgraph but a list of subgraphs so you have to iterate over list even there is only one subgraph (this is the case for karate_club_graph dataset):

```
plt.figure()
for s in S:
    nx.draw(s)
plt.show()

# For this dataset, nx.draw(G) give the same result
```

[image: karate network]